# Algorithm optimization - parallel AsyncTasks or threads?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, image-comparison

I currently have a single `AsyncTask` which currently compares images using the `bubble sort` technique using OpenCV. Say, I have to compare `400` images to each other. This would mean `400*401/2=80,200` comparisons. Let's assume one comparison takes 1 second. So, that's `80,200 sec` which is around `22.27 hours` which is ridiculously long. So, I developed an algorithm of this type:

It divides the `400` images into groups of `5`. So there are `80` images in each group.

The first part of the algorithm is the images comparing themselves within the group members.

So, `image1` will compare itself with `image2-80`, which means there are `79` comparisons. `image2` will have `78` comparisons and so on. Which makes `3,160` comparisons. Or `3,160 sec`. Similarly, `image81` will compare itself with `image82-160` and so on. So all the "group comparisons" are finished in `3,160 sec` because they're run in parallel.

The second part of the algorithm will compare `group 1` elements with `group 2` elements, `group 2` with `group 3`, `group 3` with `group 4` and so on. This would mean `image1` will be compared with `image81-160`, which is `80` comparisons and so total comparisons between `group 1` and `group 2` would be `80*80=6400` comparisons. Is it possible to have each image comparison in parallel with group comparisons? That is if `image1` is comparing itself with `image81-160` then `image2` should do the same and so on, while the other groups are doing the same. So, this part should take only `6400 sec`.

Now, `group1` will be compared with `group3`, `group2` with `group4`, `group3` with `group5`. ->`6400 sec`

After which, `group1 will be compared with group4` and `group2` with `group5`. ->`6400 sec`

So all groups are compared.

Total time = `3160+6400+6400+6400=22,360sec`. I realize the more the groups, more time it'd take. So, I'd have to increase group size to reduce the increase in time. Either way, it cuts down the time to almost `1/4th` it's actual time.

Is this algorithm unrealistic? If so, why? What are it's flaws? How would I fix it? Is there a better algorithm to compare a list of images faster? Obviously not `quick sort`, I can't arrange the images in an ascending or descending order. Or can I?

If this algorithm is possible? What would be the best way to implement it? `Thread` or `AsyncTask`?

Comment: well, I can tell you that you should be using Thread objects for these operations.  AsyncTask objects are used for operations lasting no more than a few seconds.

Comment: What image comparison means? Does it compute any total order, or partial order, or just similarity?

Comment: @Joel Could you show me an example with about 20 images or so?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov - Similarity using FREAK method.

Comment: Comparison for (in-)equality is best doen on down-sized images. You might rigourously scale the images to 32x32. For Android the best solution, and down-scaling itself might be fast. Maybe test first for a couple of random pixels.

Comment: 32x32 images don't have keypoints. The comparison will be based on hash checksums. That's very inaccurate. If two similar images have a different checksum and are scaled down, they're not going to be recognized as duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

This is a realistic algorithm, but ideally you'll want to be able to use the same number of worker threads throughout the program.  For this you'll need to use an even number of threads, say 8.

On Pass1, Thread1 processes images 1-50, Thread2 processes images 51-100, etc.

On Pass2, Thread1 and Thread2 both process images 1-100.  Thread1 processes images 1-25 and 50-75, Thread2 processes images 26-50 and images 76-100.  Then Thread1 processes images 1-25 and 76-100, and Thread2 processes images 26-75.

Passes 3 through 8 follow the same pattern - the two threads assigned to the two groups being processed split up the groups between them.  This way you keep all of your threads busy.  However, you'll need an even number of threads for this in order to simplify group partitioning.

Sample code for 4 threads

```
class ImageGroup {
    final int index1;
    final int index2;
}

class ImageComparer implements Runnable {
    final Image[] images;
    ImageGroup group1;
    ImageGroup group2;

    public ImageComparer(Image[] images, ImageGroup group1, ImageGroup group2) {
        ...
    }

    public void run() {
        if(group2 == null) { // Compare images within a single group
            for(int i = group1.index1; i < group1.index2; i++) {
                for(int j = i + 1; j < group1.inex2; j++) {
                    compare(images[i], images[j]);
                }
            }
        } else { // Compare images between two groups
            for(int i = group1.index1; i < group1.index2; i++) {
                for(int j = group2.index1; j < group2.index2; j++) {
                    compare(images[i], images[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(); // use a corePoolSize equal to the number of target threads
// for 4 threads we need 8 image groups
ImageGroup group1 = new ImageGroup(0, 50);
ImageGroup group2 = new ImageGroup(50, 100);
...
ImageGroup group8 = new ImageGroup(450, 500);

ImageComparer comparer1 = new ImageComparer(images, group1, null);
ImageComparer comparer2 = new ImageComparer(images, group3, null);
...
ImageComparer comparer4 = new ImageComparer(images, group7, null);

// submit comparers to executor service
Future future1 = executor.submit(comparer1);
Future future2 = executor.submit(comparer2);
Future future3 = executor.submit(comparer3);
Future future4 = executor.submit(comparer4);

// wait for threads to finish
future1.get();
future2.get();
future3.get();
future4.get();

comparer1 = new ImageComparer(images, group2, null);
...
comparer4 = new ImageComparer(images, group8, null);

// submit to executor, wait to finish

comparer1 = new ImageComparer(images, group1, group3);
...
comparer4 = new ImageComparer(images, group7, group6);

// submit to executor, wait to finish

comparer1 = new ImageComparer(images, group1, group4);
...
comparer4 = new ImageComparer(images, group7, group5);
```

Comment: Also, isn't 2 threads less? I was planning on having 4 threads, each doing it's own set of comparison for each pass parallel with the other threads.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was only describing the execution of 2 out of 8 threads.  I've added some example code to my answer for how to partition the images among 4 threads.